# "--strictFunctionTypes" and inference of generic union types

Tags: typescript

I faced with some problem in my project which is totally unclear to me

```
// =========================== RxJS types imitation ===========================================================

interface Subscription {
    unsubscribe(): void
}

type Subscribe<T> = (value: T) => void

interface Observable<T> {
    subscribe(subscribe: Subscribe<T>): Subscription
}

interface Subject<T> {
    next(value: T): void
    subscribe(subscribe: Subscribe<T>): Subscription
}


// =========================== My custom types ===========================================================


export interface Reducer<S, A> {
  (state: S, action: A): S;
}

export interface Effect<A, S> {
  (action$: Subject<A>, state$: Observable<S>): Subscription;
}

export interface OptionalParams<S, A> {
  effects?: Effect<A, S>[];
}


// =========================== Reproducing concrete types and variables ===========================================================

const initialState = {
  some: true
}

type State = typeof initialState

interface BaseAction<T extends string> {
  type: T
}

interface ActionA extends BaseAction<"A"> {
  payload: string
}

interface ActionB extends BaseAction<"B"> {
  payload: number
}

interface ActionC extends BaseAction<"C"> {
  payload: boolean
}

declare const reducer: Reducer<State, ActionA | ActionB | ActionC>

declare const outerAction$: Observable<ActionA | ActionB>

declare function createState$<S, A>(
  reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
  initialState: S,
  outerAction$: Observable<A>,
  optionalParams?: OptionalParams<S, A>,
): Observable<S>


// =========================== Reproducing the problem ===========================================================

const state$1 = createState$(reducer, initialState, outerAction$)

declare const someEffect: Effect<ActionA | ActionB | ActionC, State>

const state$2 = createState$(reducer, initialState, outerAction$, {
  effects: [
    someEffect,
  ]
})
```

[the same code in typescript playground (please switch on/off strictFunctionTypes option and hover createState$ function in the last section)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%20RxJS%20types%20imitation%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0A%0Ainterface%20Subscription%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20unsubscribe()%3A%20void%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Subscribe%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(value%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0A%0Ainterface%20Observable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20subscribe(subscribe%3A%20Subscribe%3CT%3E)%3A%20Subscription%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Subject%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20next(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%0A%20%20%20%20subscribe(subscribe%3A%20Subscribe%3CT%3E)%3A%20Subscription%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%20My%20custom%20types%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0A%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20Reducer%3CS%2C%20A%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20(state%3A%20S%2C%20action%3A%20A)%3A%20S%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20Effect%3CA%2C%20S%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20(action%24%3A%20Subject%3CA%3E%2C%20state%24%3A%20Observable%3CS%3E)%3A%20Subscription%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20OptionalParams%3CS%2C%20A%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20effects%3F%3A%20Effect%3CA%2C%20S%3E%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%20Reproducing%20concrete%20types%20and%20variables%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0A%0Aconst%20initialState%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20some%3A%20true%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20State%20%3D%20typeof%20initialState%0A%0Ainterface%20BaseAction%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ActionA%20extends%20BaseAction%3C%22A%22%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20payload%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ActionB%20extends%20BaseAction%3C%22B%22%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20payload%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ActionC%20extends%20BaseAction%3C%22C%22%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20payload%3A%20boolean%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20reducer%3A%20Reducer%3CState%2C%20ActionA%20%7C%20ActionB%20%7C%20ActionC%3E%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20outerAction%24%3A%20Observable%3CActionA%20%7C%20ActionB%3E%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20createState%24%3CS%2C%20A%3E(%0A%20%20reducer%3A%20Reducer%3CS%2C%20A%3E%2C%0A%20%20initialState%3A%20S%2C%0A%20%20outerAction%24%3A%20Observable%3CA%3E%2C%0A%20%20optionalParams%3F%3A%20OptionalParams%3CS%2C%20A%3E%2C%0A)%3A%20Observable%3CS%3E%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%20Reproducing%20the%20problem%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0A%0Aconst%20state%241%20%3D%20createState%24(reducer%2C%20initialState%2C%20outerAction%24)%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20someEffect%3A%20Effect%3CActionA%20%7C%20ActionB%20%7C%20ActionC%2C%20State%3E%0A%0Aconst%20state%242%20%3D%20createState%24(reducer%2C%20initialState%2C%20outerAction%24%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20effects%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20someEffect%2C%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D)%0A)

If `--sctrictFunctionTypes` option is enabled, hovering `createState$` function in the last section will show that generic `A` is inferred not as type `ActionA | ActionB | ActionC` but `ActionA | ActionB`. I don't understand how `--sctrictFunctionTypes` affects union inference. I thought that typescript will try to infer the most common union type. This knowledge is essential to me because I need the type of `action$` argument to be `Subject<ActionA | ActionB | ActionC>` for my effects defined as inline arrow functions. More than that: if I add an arrow-function-effect below `someEffect`, I'll get an error from typescript (v3.1+) in my project saying `Types of property 'effects' are incompatible`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, TypeScript infers the type argument for a type parameter of a function call by matching up the argument types against the parameter types and generating a set of "inferences" for each type parameter.  Each inference is either "covariant" or "contravariant" depending on whether the type of the inference matched an occurrence of the type parameter in a covariant or a contravariant position.  Then there are rules that determine the final inferred type of the type parameter based on the set of covariant and contravariant inferences.  `strictFunctionTypes` can affect whether certain positions are considered covariant or contravariant and thereby change the final result.  I haven't worked out the details of what happens in your example; if you're curious, look at the `inferTypes` and `getInferredType` functions in the TypeScript [checker](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/src/compiler/checker.ts).

I understand that your practical problem is that you are writing an inline arrow function `(a, s) => { ... }` in the `effects` array and you want `a` to get a contextual type of `Subject<ActionA | ActionB | ActionC>` so that you can call `a.next` with an `ActionC`.  I can think of a few ways you can achieve this:

1. Lower the "inference priority" of the occurrence in `A` in the type of the `outerAction$` parameter to `createState$` by using a dummy intersection:

   ```
   declare function createState$<S, A>(
     reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
     initialState: S,
     outerAction$: Observable<A & {dummy?: undefined}>,
     optionalParams?: OptionalParams<S, A>,
   ): Observable<S>
   ```

   Then the inference for `A` from `reducer` will take priority over the one from `outerAction$`.  However, changing the type of `outerAction$` might have undesired side effects.
2. Add a dummy property of type `A` to `Reducer` so that the `reducer` parameter gives you a covariant inference instead of just a contravariant inference:

   ```
   export interface Reducer<S, A> {
     (state: S, action: A): S;
     _dummy?: A;
   }
   ```

   However, this might have undesired side effects on other uses of the `Reducer` interface.
3. Pass explicit type arguments on the call to `createState$`.
4. Break `createState$` into a curried function that takes the reducer and returns another function that takes the remaining arguments.  Then the type arguments for `S` and `A` will be fixed based on the reducer during the first function call and won't be affected by `outerAction$`.